# Adding labels to a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php

This is the full code I have:

```
<?php
require_once ("comconfig.php");
require_once ("../function.php");

if (isset ($_COOKIE["accessattempt"]) && !$access_code_required) {
    setcookie("accessattempt", "", time()-3600);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
    <title><?php echo $sitename; ?>Name of page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wubai = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <?php 
        if (!empty ($css)) 
        echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='".$css."'>\r\n";
    ?>
</head>

<body>
    <a name="top" id="top">gotop</a>

    <ul class="nav" style="position: fixed;height: auto">
    <a href="#top" target="_self"><img src="../images/iconInputSearchClean.png" /></a>
    <?php 
    $all_letters = array('33','35','40','45','50','60');
        for($i=0;$i<count($all_letters);$i++){

            echo "<li style='padding: 2px 0' id='short_index' class='$all_letters[$i]'>"."$all_letters[$i]".'</li>';
        }
    ?>    
    </ul>
    <?php if (file_exists ($header)) include ($header); ?>
    <div class='style8' style="height: auto">Name of page</button></div></a></div>
    <p align='center'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

            <table class="select_descript" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" valign="middle"><tbody><tr><td>Name of page</td></tr></tbody></table>
            <p class="style_tweaks11">

            <?php
            $file = 'songfile.txt';
            $content = file_get_contents($file);
            $array = explode("\r\n", $content);
            for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
            {
                $array1 = explode(" - ", $array[$i]);
                $artists[]=$array1["0"];
                $songname[]=$array1["1"];
            } 
            for($i=0; $i<count($artists); $i++){
                echo "<div class='songdetail'>
                        <form method=\"post\" action=\"".$script."\" name=\"top20_form\" onsubmit=\"return check()\">
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rq\" value=\"NA\">
                            <input type=hidden name=request_artist value=\"$artists[$i]\">
                            <input type=hidden name=request_title value=\"$songname[$i]\">
                            <input type=hidden name=func value='Send Your Request'>
                            <button type=submit name='submit' class=submit_button onclick='javascript:setCookie();'><div class='changeline' id='".(1+$i)."'>".(1+$i).". ".$artists[$i]." - ".$songname[$i]."</div></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>";
                }
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In particular I am focusing on this section excatly:

```
<?php 
    $all_letters = array('33','35','40','45','50','60');
        for($i=0;$i<count($all_letters);$i++){

            echo "<li style='padding: 2px 0' id='short_index' class='$all_letters[$i]'>"."$all_letters[$i]".'</li>';
        }
    ?>
```

This code basically adds a javascript based floating menu at the top right hand corner of the screen, see http://screencast.com/t/9XhdAHFL

The Purpose of the menu, is there's a list of songs in a text file which this PHP file refers to **songfile.txt** There's 779 songs in the text file, and this PHP script grabs all the 779 songs and lists them on the website. What the little javascript menu does is allows me to display a series of numbers, users can click on any number and are taken to the exact spot on the page.

What I want to do is add labels in place of the numbers which display in the little javascript menu, the labels being for the user to see, but underlining this, I need to make sure the menu's function remains, when a menu item is clicked, the user is taken to this place on the page.

Comment: where are you going to take labels from?

Comment: As for the labels, I will hard code them in the code.

Comment: not sure what you want, but see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29576530/2545680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to something like this indexed array

```
<?php 
   $all_letters = array(array('33' ,"SonG Name"),array('35', "Song Name"));
   for($i=0;$i<count($all_letters);$i++){
       echo "<li style='padding: 2px 0' id='short_index' class='".$all_letters[$i][0]."'></label>".$all_letters[$i][1]."</label></li>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it brings up a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$all_letters = [
    "label1" => '33',
    "label2" => '35'
];

foreach ($all_letters as $label => $value) {
    echo "<li class='$value'><a href='#$value'>$label</a></li>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine and outputs the following:

```
*label1
*label2
```

If when clicked will change URL to either `/#33` or `/#35`. If you've copied it and it still doesn't output anything than the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: When I add this new code snipit to the script replacing the previous code snipit, I save it and the Web page comes up blank

Comment: well, I thought you wanted to show you the way, not write the code for you. Update your answer with the response that comes from server.

Comment: There's no response, just a blank page when I refresh the page